# Java.lang.NullPointerException в Map при чтении и записи в Hive

Tags: map-reduce, java, hadoop

Добрый день! Возникает следующая ошибка, не могу понять причину. Проверила данные в таблице dmg_bindings, они ненулевые, партиция также присутствует.

**Код Driver**:

```
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configured;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.NullWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.WritableComparable;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.MultipleInputs;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.TextInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.TextOutputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.util.Tool;
import org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner;
import org.apache.hive.hcatalog.data.DefaultHCatRecord;
import org.apache.hive.hcatalog.data.schema.HCatFieldSchema;
import org.apache.hive.hcatalog.data.schema.HCatSchema;
import org.apache.hive.hcatalog.mapreduce.HCatInputFormat;
import org.apache.hive.hcatalog.mapreduce.HCatOutputFormat;
import org.apache.hive.hcatalog.mapreduce.InputJobInfo;
import org.apache.hive.hcatalog.mapreduce.OutputJobInfo;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.*;

public class Driver extends Configured implements Tool{
    @Override
    public int run(String[] strings) throws Exception {
        Configuration conf = getConf();
        Job job = Job.getInstance(conf, "newDmg");
        job.setJarByClass(Driver.class);
        job.setMapperClass(MapNewDmg.class);
        job.setNumReduceTasks(0);

        HCatInputFormat.setInput(job, "default", "dmg_bindings", "dt=\"2014-09-01\"");
        job.setInputFormatClass(HCatInputFormat.class);
        job.setOutputKeyClass(NullWritable.class);
        job.setOutputValueClass(DefaultHCatRecord.class);
        job.setOutputFormatClass(HCatOutputFormat.class);

        Map staticPartitions = new HashMap<String, String>(1);
        staticPartitions.put("dt", "2014-09-01");
        List dynamicPartitions = new ArrayList<String>();
        dynamicPartitions.add("platid1");
        dynamicPartitions.add("platid2");

        OutputJobInfo jobInfo = OutputJobInfo.create("default", "newdmgbnd", staticPartitions);
        jobInfo.setDynamicPartitioningKeys(dynamicPartitions);

        HCatOutputFormat.setOutput(job, jobInfo);

        HCatSchema schema = HCatOutputFormat.getTableSchema(job);
        schema.append(new HCatFieldSchema("platid1", HCatFieldSchema.Type.STRING, ""));
        schema.append(new HCatFieldSchema("platid2", HCatFieldSchema.Type.STRING, ""));

        HCatOutputFormat.setSchema(job, schema);

        return job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        int exitcode = ToolRunner.run(new Driver(), args);
        System.exit(exitcode);
    }
}
```

**Код Map:**

```
import org.apache.hadoop.io.NullWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.WritableComparable;
import org.apache.hive.hcatalog.data.DefaultHCatRecord;
import org.apache.hive.hcatalog.data.HCatRecord;
import org.apache.hive.hcatalog.data.schema.HCatFieldSchema;
import org.apache.hive.hcatalog.data.schema.HCatSchema;
import org.apache.hive.hcatalog.mapreduce.HCatInputFormat;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;

public class MapNewDmg extends Mapper<NullWritable, HCatRecord, NullWritable, HCatRecord> {
    @Override
    protected void map(NullWritable key, HCatRecord value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        String viuserid = (String) value.get(0);
        if (viuserid == null)
            return;
        String puid = (String) value.get(1);
        if (puid == null)
            return;;
        Long ts = (Long) value.get(2);
        if (ts == 0)
            return;
        String pid = (String) value.get(4);
        if (pid == null)
            return;
        int newts = (int) (ts / 1000);
        if (newts == 0)
            return;
        HCatRecord record = new DefaultHCatRecord(6);
        record.set(0, newts);
        record.set(1, viuserid);
        record.set(2, puid);
        record.set(4, "586");
        record.set(5, pid);
        context.write(NullWritable.get(), record);
    }
}
```

**Ошибка**

> 15/01/23 13:22:40 INFO
> mapred.JobClient: Running job:
> job_201501221242_0023 15/01/23
> 13:22:41 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map
> 0% reduce 0% 15/01/23 13:22:53 INFO
> mapred.JobClient: Task Id :
> attempt_201501221242_0023_m_000019_0,
> Status : FAILED
> ***java.lang.NullPointerException***  at
> org.apache.hive.hcatalog.mapreduce.FileRecordWriterContainer.write(FileRecordWriterContainer.java:167)
>   at
> org.apache.hive.hcatalog.mapreduce.FileRecordWriterContainer.write(FileRecordWriterContainer.java:53)
>   at
> org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$NewDirectOutputCollector.write(MapTask.java:558)
>   at
> org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.TaskInputOutputContextImpl.write(TaskInputOutputContextImpl.java:85)
>   at
> org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.map.WrappedMapper$Context.write(WrappedMapper.java:106)
>   at MapNewDmg.map(MapNewDmg.java:43)
>   at MapNewDmg.map(MapNewDmg.java:16)
>   at
> org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.run(Mapper.java:140)
>   at
> org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:672)
>   at
> org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:330)
>   at
> org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:268)
>   at
> java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native
> Method)   at
> javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
>   at
> org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(Use
> attempt_201501221242_0023_m_000019_0:
> SLF4J: Class path contains multiple
> SLF4J bindings.
> attempt_201501221242_0023_m_000019_0:
> SLF4J: Found binding in
> [jar:file:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.2.0-1.cdh5.2.0.p0.36/jars/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.5.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
> attempt_201501221242_0023_m_000019_0:
> SLF4J: Found binding in
> [jar:file:/mnt1/mapred/local/taskTracker/mvolosnikova/jobcache/job_201501221242_0023/jars/job.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
> attempt_201501221242_0023_m_000019_0:
> SLF4J: See
> http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings
> for an explanation.
> attempt_201501221242_0023_m_000019_0:
> SLF4J: Actual binding is of type
> [org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory]

***Почему возникает NullPointerExeption?***

Comment: Очевидно, что шибка возникает в классе `FileRecordWriterContainer` в строке 167. Смотрите, что происходит там и вверх по стеку.

Comment: @a_gura, не получится, запускаю на сторонней машине.
То есть Вы думаете, что это проблема не в моем коде?

Comment: @marinarazdvatri Причем здесь сторонняя машина. Просто смотрите в исходный код. Проблема вероятнее всего в вашем коде, т.к. именно из него приходит значение `null`.

Answer (score 3):

Ошибка скорее всего из-за того, что Вы подаёте в `Context` ключ типа `NullWritable`.
Если ключ Вам не нужен, то вместо `NullWritable` лучше сделать фиктивный числовой ключ (`InteWritable` или `LongWritable`), инициализировать его какой-нибудь константой (чтоб зря не тратить память на объекты) и подавать каждый раз в `Context`. Например:

```
    public class MapNewDmg extends Mapper<IntWritable, HCatRecord, IntWritable, HCatRecord> {
        public static IntWritable fictiveKey = new IntWritable(1);

        @Override
        protected void map(IntWritable key, HCatRecord value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
            // весь метод без изменений
            context.write(key, record);
        }
    }
```